# Integrating $\iint e^{-\frac23(x^2-xy+y^2)}dxdy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> How to integrate $$\large\displaystyle \iint e^{-\frac23(x^2-xy+y^2)} \, \mathrm{d}x \,  \mathrm{d}y$$

I don't know how to start, change of variable into polar coordinates is not possible, because of the middle part.

Can you help please ?

Comment: I think that polar is fine if you first integrate $r$. Moreover, substitute $2sinxcosx=Sin2x$

Comment: Use completing the square is the first thing you should do and then you will have term that is ~$(ax+by)^2$, but  I have no doubt you can handle that :)

Comment: I got $-\frac16((x+y)^2+3(x-y)^2)$

Comment: sorry i should of been more explicit with my comment. But you have accepted an answer so it does not matter now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following variable change will allow you to separate the double integral into the product of two: $$u=x+y,\quad v=x-y $$

$${x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-xy=\frac{1}{4}\,{u}^{2}+\frac{3}{4}\,{v}^{2}$$

Comment: I think I got it

, thank to your hint:

$\large e^{-\frac16(u^2+3v^2)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{-\frac16(u^2+t^2)}=-6\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{(r^2+s^2)}$ and the Jacobian of the inverse is $-\frac12$

Hence $-6\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(-\frac12)(\int\int e^{(r^2+s^2)})=\sqrt3\pi$

Comment: @OBDA Happy to help, I agree with your result.